# How can I refactor a constructor so its real dependencies are clear?

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, constructor, refactoring

Let's say that class `PersonList` has the method `AddNewPerson()`, which creates and adds a new `Person` to an internal list. However, the constructor of `Person` requires several parameters (mostly interfaces it depends on). This means that `PersonList` will also require to have those parameters passed to *its* constructor (or somehow made available).

This arrangement seems like a code smell because `PersonList` doesn't use any of those dependencies directly. It simply passes them along to another's constructor. How may I refactor these classes so that it's clear what the real dependencies are for each class?

Comment: Please show some code (at least an outline what the classes look like).  PersonList sounds like a DTO or Model, not a service, so it sounds like it shouldn't have dependencies (meaning you are on the right track). But it is unlikely anyone can tell you "how to refactor it", when we don't really have an idea what we are dealing with.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I simplified the problem to get to the essence of the issue, but I may have oversimplified it. In my actual case, these classes are view models for an MVVM application. `PersonListViewModel` has an `AddCommand` that is relayed to a the method that creates and adds a new `PersonViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "This means that PersonList will also require to have those parameters
>   passed to its constructor (or somehow made available)."

Why would that be? `PersonList` doesn't have to be a factory for `Person` objects, you can pass `Person`s directly to `AddNewPerson` instead.

E.g.

```
public void AddNewPerson(Person person);
```

However, if you both wishes to relieve the client code from creating `Person` instances and at the same time you want to avoid having `PersonList` to depend on what's needed to create `Person`s then you may introduce a `PersonFactory` that would encapsulate the creation logic as well as the dependencies needed.

In that case the client can either use the `PersonFactory` to create `Person`s and add them to the list or the `PersonList` can depend on the `PersonFactory`.

Comment: Due to the architecture of my application, the `AddNewPerson` method cannot have any parameters, so the factory class is a viable option.

Comment: @redcurry In that case using the factory from the list might be a good idea or you could also take the dependencies hit directly in `PersonList`...